# Running frequencies to see combinations of values for one variable

Tags: spss, frequency

I have one variable (type of medication) that has about 16 different values (e.g., aspirin, metformin, etc.). As I was completing a variety of characteristics for this variable, each medication is listed as a case in SPSS (ie 16 long for 16 medications).

I was hoping there could be a way to run frequencies of combinations that occur for this variable (eg, frequency that this combination occurs in the variable: aspirin + metformin).

I hope that made sense, thank you in advance!

Comment: This is just a counting problem. Each of the 16 drugs would either be a yes (1) or a no (0). So, counting in binary, we would have numbers like 0010011001100110, where each place is a drug choice yes/no. Then to see what's what, for example for drug 1 with three, count up all the choices numbered 1's in position 1 and 3: xxxxxxxxxxxxx1x1; suppose there are 4 of them and suppose we have 10000 16 place drug combination entries. Then the frequency of drug 1 and 3 taken together is $\dfrac{4}{10000}=0.04\%$.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have other variables in the dataset, and that you have a single identifier column (referred to as 'Identifier', and the variable containing the medications is called 'Medications'.

Change 'FLAG.Var1 TO FLAG.VarN' to represent the first and last FLAG variables after you restructure.

```
DATASET COPY COMBINATIONS.
DATASET ACTIVATE COMBINATIONS.
MATCH FILES /FILE = *
/KEEP = Identifier Medications.
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE FLAG = 1.
EXECUTE.
ALTER TYPE FLAG (F12.0).
ALTER TYPE FLAG (A12).
SORT CASES BY Identifier Medications.
CASESTOVARS
  /ID= Identifier 
  /INDEX=Medications
  /GROUPBY=VARIABLE.
STRING Combination (A64).
COMPUTE Combination = CONCAT(FLAG.Var1 TO FLAG.VarN).
EXECUTE.
FRE Combination.
```